# How to convert object to a vertically-formatted csv list

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to export a custom PS object to CSV, but format it as a vertical list.

When I call

```
$object | Export-Csv -Path "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\out.csv" -force
```

or

```
$object | ConvertTo-Csv | clip
```

The output always displays the object properties horizontally, meaning when viewing them in excel we will need to scroll to the righ to view all properties.

How can I output the object to display the properties vertically?

**Current Output**

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"one","two","three"
"1","2","3"
```

**Required Output**

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"one","1"
"two","2"
"three","3"
```

Is this possible using PS commands, or will I have to manually build the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the members of the object. Create a new custom object having 'name' and 'value' corresponding to each member you want.

Here's a simple example:

```
$object = [pscustomobject]@{one=1;two=2;three=3}
# not what you want
$object | ConvertTo-Csv

# what you want
$object | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject] @{Name=$_.name;Value=$object.($_.Name)}
    } | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Perhaps a more succinct answer:

```
$object |
    Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
    Select-Object @{name='Name';expression={$_.name}},
                  @{name='Value';expression={$object.($_.name)}} |
    ConvertTo-Csv
```